# highcharts datalabels hidden

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to make a bar chart using a highcharts, it was work as it was, but there is some issue with it. When the show multiple indicators, the datalabels is hidden. Like this - datalabels provinsi aceh is hidden:

[image] how to make it appear but not overlapping the rest of it. the max of indicators is 4.

here is my graph

```
Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
                            chart: {
                              type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                              text: chartname,
                              align: 'center'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                series: {
                                pointPadding: 0.4,
                                groupPadding: 0.1
                              }
                            },  
                            tooltip: {
                                shared: true,
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                              type: 'category',
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                              series: {
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                dataLabels: {
                                  enabled: true
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            series: grafikmaindata,
                            drilldown: seriessubgrafik[0],
                            exporting: {
                                buttons: {
                                    copyToClipboard: {
                                        text: 'Copy Chart',
                                        _titleKey: 'contextButtonTitle',
                                        align: 'right',
                                        onclick: function () {
                                            // Call the function to copy the chart to the clipboard
                                            copyHtmlToClipboard(this.container);
                                        },            
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: We can't fix pictures. Please provide a [mre] of your issue with relevant code and data. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force all dataLabels to show, enable the `allowOverlap` option:

```
  dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true
      }
```

You can move overlaping dataLabels by updating their `y` position:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load() {
        let point = this.series[2].points[3];
        point.update({
          x: point.x,
          dataLabels: {
            y: 10
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f2h81wbt/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.allowOverlap
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.y